# PWA - Avoid opening a browser window for Google Single Sign On

Tags: android, single-sign-on, google-signin, progressive-web-apps

Is it possible to stay within the in-app-full-screen experience when letting the user login via Google Single Sign On?

It used to work until recent changes about the manifest scope but currently, my users see a new browser window to enter their Google Credentials even if my PWA is properly installed on the mobile. 
After validating the user (going through accounts.google.com URL), the user gets redirected again to the full screen experience but what I am trying to accomplish is to complete the Google Sign On process within the full-screen app-like experience.

I have even tried **scope: "*"** within the manifest, to no avail.

I could not find whether this is even possible or *by Google design*

Thanks!
Miguel

Comment: Sounds like you are referring to a full-screen mobile web experience? This is by design so that if user has to enter their google.com credentials, it's done in a context where the user can can check it's the system browser and verify the URL address to protect again being phished.

Comment: Indeed. Your explanation makes sense. If only you happen to have any 'official' link with that information, I would close this question as answered. I do not lose hope yet as support for PWAs is growing rapidly and would not be surprised if Google enables this SSO more transparently (if not already done so)